# Octagon symmetry and base change

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble with this question in my course.

I am to consider a regular octagon with vertices A, B, C, D, E, F, G and H in counter clockwise order.

The vector $\overrightarrow{u}$, wich has the coordinates $(1,2)$ in the base $e_1=\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $e_2=\overrightarrow{AE}$. I am supposed to express $\overrightarrow{u}$ coordinates in the base $f_1=\overrightarrow{AC}$, $f_2=\overrightarrow{AH}$.

I have done this exercise in a regular hexagon. But I do not know how to derive the symmetries in an octagon to so that I can express the vector in the new base.

Need some good guidance,

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(**Hint**) Let's say you have an octagon like this:

[image]

Consider a coordinate system such that $AB=\sqrt2$ lies along the $x$ axis and $A$ is the origin. In the standard basis, $e_1=(\sqrt2,0)$, $e_2=(\sqrt2,2+\sqrt2)$.

You have $u=e_1+2e_2$, which will give you the components of $u$. Similarly, can you find the standard basis components of $f_1$ and $f_2$ as we did for $e_1$ and $e_2$? After that, assuming $u=af_1+bf_2$, you can solve for $a$ and $b$ via a pair of simultaneous equations.

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance, this I believe is really helpful! Thank you!

Comment: I've got that $f_1=(1+\sqrt{2},2)$ and $f_2=(-1,\sqrt{2})$. But I'm not quite sure on how to use these basis components to set up the equations to solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @MisterButter: You'll need to revise your calculations for $f_1$ and $f_2$. Maybe I should've clarified, my bad. So imagine $A$ as the origin, $AB$ along the positive $x$ axis. Naturally, $AF$ will be along the positive $y$ axis. In this system, what will be the coordinates of points $C$ and $H$? That'll give you representations for vectors $AC$ and $AH$ since $A$ is the origin.

Comment: Ah sorry, I believe I see my misstakes. $f_1=(\sqrt2+1,\sqrt2)$ and $f_2=(-1,1)$, I'm I correct?

Comment: @MisterButter: $f_2$ is correct, but $f_1=(\sqrt2+1,1)$. So now what will be the coordinates of $af_1+bf_2$? And what will be the coordinates of $e_1+2e_2$? You can equate those coordinates to get two equations that you can solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Well now you are trying to explain the part where I'm really lost. Thank you for trying but I'm lost here.

Comment: But my guess is that $e_1+2e_2=(4, 4+2\sqrt2)$

Comment: $e_1+2\cdot e_2=1\cdot (\sqrt2, 0)+2\cdot (\sqrt2, 2+\sqrt2 )=(1\cdot \sqrt2+2\cdot \sqrt2, 1\cdot 0+2\cdot (2+\sqrt2 ))=(3\cdot \sqrt2, 4+2\cdot \sqrt2)$

Comment: @Dr.RichardKlitzing Thank you, I see why my calculation was wrong!

Comment: So now we now $e_1+2e_2 = (3\sqrt{2},4+2\sqrt{2})$ and that $af_1+bf_2=(3\sqrt{2},4+2\sqrt{2})$. But we have two unknown and one equation so there is no unambiguous solution. I'm missing something here.

Comment: I'm stupid. These should be the two equations $(1+\sqrt2)a-b=3\sqrt2$ and $a+b=4+2sqrt2$

Comment: @ShirishKulhari Thank you for your patients and help, I believe I have come to an answer $a=-1+3\sqrt2$ and $b=5-\sqrt2$

Comment: @MisterButter: Right answer! My feedback is you may want to get the fundamentals / basics perfect. Look at lots of solved examples. Then try some on your own

Comment: @ShirishKulhari Highly appreciate it, thank you!